# Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I'm relatively new to C++ (as you can probably tell by the question) and I've hit a problem. I have two files: Drives.h and Drives.cpp

Drives.h

```
#pragma once

enum MountMode
{
    User,
    System,
    Both,
    Auto
};

class Drive
{
public:
    Drive(void);
    ~Drive(void);

    BOOL Mount(MountMode mode);
    VOID Unmount(void);
    BOOL IsConnected(void);

    static char* DeviceName;
    static char* DrivePath;
};

class Drives
{
public:
    Drives(void);
    ~Drives(void);
};
```

and my Drives.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Drives.h"

Drives::Drives(void)
{
    Drive USB0; //Error happening here
}

Drives::~Drives(void)
{
}
```

The error is saying that the Drives class constructor, destructor and IsConnected() are all unresolved externals. I'm not sure what I'm missing since I set this class up like the one on cplusplus.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, you have not implemented the constructor and destructor of `Drive`:

```
Drive::Drive(void) {
    ...
}

Drive::~Drive(void) {
    ...
}
```

Creating a local variable of class type (as you do in `Drive USB0;`) will invoke that class' constructor, and the destructor will be invoked at the end of the variable's scope; hence the error.

You should implement the other functions of `Drive` too - declaring a function in a class declaration is essentially a promise that the function will be implemented somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those methods have been declared in the Drive class in your header file, but you haven't actually created a body for these methods.

You must either create a body inline in your header file, create a body in a CPP file, or make sure you are linking with an existing file that defines these methods. Otherwise, the error is right, these methods have not been defined.

Answer (score 2):

An Unresolved External Symbol error *usually* means you have provided a declaration of a function but not its definition.

In your case, since you declared `Drive(void)` and `~Drive(void)` the compiler removes its defaults and expects your definitions to exist, which they don't, so it throws an error.

As a side note: using `void` in place of empty parenthesis to mean "This function takes no arguments" is a C-Style definition and should not be used.

Also,**do not** use `#pragma once` as a substitute for include guards. It is a Microsoft-Specific construct and is not compatible with other compilers. Use actual include guards instead:

```c
 
#ifndef CLASS_NAME_H
#define CLASS_NAME_H
//CODE HERE
#endif
```

Comment: Not compatible with other compilers? That actually made me laugh.

Comment: @Casey : `#pragma once` works just fine with clang, GCC, Intel, Borland, etc. Calling it "Microsoft-specific" is definitely a bit silly.

Comment: @ildjarn: It's still non-standard.

Comment: @George : I didn't claim that it was standard, only that it's not Microsoft-specific and that it _is_ compatible with _most_ other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code you declare two classes(`Drive` and `Drives`), but you provide the implementation only for one (`Drives`)

```
#pragma once

enum MountMode
{
    User,
    System,
    Both,
    Auto
};

class Drive
{
public:
    Drive(void);
    ~Drive(void);

    BOOL Mount(MountMode mode);
    VOID Unmount(void);
    BOOL IsConnected(void);

    static char* DeviceName;
    static char* DrivePath;
};

class Drives
{
public:
    Drives(void);
    ~Drives(void);
};
```

To get rid of the error message, you must include an implementation for Drive's class methods. On way to extend your Drives.cpp so that your code may work looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Drives.h"

//Drive class constructor
Drive::Drive(void)
{
   //Add initialization code here. For example:
   DeviceName = "Name";
   DrivePath = "";
}

//Drive class destructor
Drive::~Drive(void)
{
}

//Also add the implementation for Mount
BOOL Drive::Mount(MountMode mode)
{
  //implementation for Mount. For example:
  return FALSE;
}

//Also add the implementation for Mount
VOID Drive::Unmount()
{
  //implementation for Unmount
}

//Also add the implementation for Mount
BOOL Drive::IsConnected()
{
  //implementation for IsConnected.For example:
  return FALSE;
}


//Drives class constructor
Drives::Drives(void)
{
    Drive USB0; //Error happening here
}

//Drives class destructor
Drives::~Drives(void)
{
}
```

It is also possible if you copy paste-d the code, that you also have the implementation for the `Drive` class but you save it in another .cpp file, like `Drive.cpp`. In that case you should either copy all the implementation methods from the other `Drive.cpp` file to `Drives.cpp`. Or you should move the declaration of `Drive` class from `Drives.h` to `Drive.h`. In that case you will have clear separation for classes in different files, which is good, but you will have to include `Drive.h` in the `Drives.h` file.